# Cut avi video to another avi without losing quality using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a .avi video. I need to cut a piece of it as another .avi file. When I do this I lose quality in the cut file:

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -ss 00:34:00 -t 00:10:00 -async 1 cut.avi`

However, if I convert it to .mp4 in the same way I get good quality:

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -ss 00:34:00 -t 00:10:00 -async 1 cut.mp4`

I was wondering how I can get .avi output file and also maintain the good quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:34:00 -i input.avi -t 00:10:00 -codec copy cut.avi
```

This will [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) all stream types from your original file.

Comment: The `-t 00:10:00` will copy 10 minutes of duration to the output stream. To specify start position and stop position of the input stream do like so: `ffmpeg -ss 00:05:25 -to 02:23:23 -i input.avi -codec copy output.avi`. With the clock of the input stream this will skip everything before 5:25 minutes and everything after position 2:23:23 hours